# Uncaught exception 'Predis\Response\ServerException' with message 'MOVED 7369

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, redis-cluster

Getting this *error* :

> [error] 1118#1118: *366 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Predis\Response\ServerException' with message 'MOVED 7369 10.0.213.16:6379'

My **Redis connection code** is:

```
$parameters = array(
                    "scheme" => "tcp",
                    "host" => "testingredis.akf46e.clustercfg.use1.cache.amazonaws.com",
                    "port" => 6379,
                    "database" => 0,
                );


$db = new Predis\Client($parameters, $options);
```

**Note**: The above code is working fine in local but not working in my AWS server. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
After lots of research successfully completed the redis cluster with the AWS elasticache.
 
$options    = array('cluster' => 'redis');
    $parameters = array(
        'clusters' => array(
            'default' => array(
                    'scheme' => 'tcp',
                    'host' => HOST_URL,
                    'port' => 6379,
                    'database' => 0
            ),
        ),
    );

    $db = new Predis\Client($parameters,$options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Were struggling with same. this is short version of what works:

```
$redis = new Predis\Client(
   ['tcp://127.0.0.1:6379'],
   ['cluster' => 'redis']
);
```